# Token2022 Error - Incorrect Program ID for Instruction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, token, token-2022

So I'm creating a Token2022 token for testing purposes right now, and I want to use the withdraw fee extension to hold a percentage on transfer and use my withdrawal authority account to capture those held fees into my account and use them for other purposes. This all works as expected, but I notice on certain occasions, the logic I have for creating a destination account for the token, and use that in the transfer instruction, sometimes it'll error out and say `Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction`. But it'll only do this 3 or 4 times before the transaction goes through.

Could this be a devnet issue, an RPC issue, or could this be related to priority fees? The Token-2022 program ID I'm passing down is definitely the correct one, so I'm not sure. This is part of the hook I wrote.

```
const transferWithFee = async(): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const token = new PublicKey('')
            const sourceAccount = new PublicKey('')

            const accountKeypair = Keypair.generate();
            
            const destinationAccount = await createAccount(
                connection,
                owner,
                token,
                owner.publicKey,
                accountKeypair,
                undefined,
                TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
            );

            const transferAmount = BigInt(1000 * Math.pow(10, decimals)); // Transfer 1000 tokens
            const calcFee = (transferAmount * BigInt(feeBasisPoints)) / BigInt(10000); // expect 50 fee
            const fee = calcFee > maxFee ?  maxFee : calcFee;

            const transaction = new Transaction().add(
                createTransferCheckedWithFeeInstruction(
                    sourceAccount,
                    token,
                    destinationAccount,
                    sourceAccountOwner.publicKey,
                    transferAmount,
                    decimals,
                    fee,
                    [],
                    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
                )
            );

            const sig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, sourceAccountOwner]);
            console.log('transfer sig: ', sig)
        } catch ( error ) {
            console.log('error minting and/or transferring token: ', error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're trying to create an account on a totally new mint, and the mint creation transaction hasn't been confirmed by the network yet? "Incorrect program id" could also mean that a token or mint account isn't properly initialized

Comment: It's strange because it hasn't appeared since. Only happened once.